# How to dynamically edit dns entries without restarting the dns server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, tomcat

I am trying to host multiple sites on a single webapp in a tomcat server.
For example
www.abc.com, www.xyz.com and several sites fetch content from my webapp hosted on tomcat with apache as the web server.
My web app is hosted at www.mysite.com.
www.abc.com should forward to www.mysite.com?id=abc
www.xyz.com should forward to www.mysite.com?id=xyz

Can you tell me how to configure dns entries, apache and tomcat configuration to achieve this scenario??
These site will have to be added dynamically! so is there any way to update the dns entries dynamically without restarting the dns server ... and similarly for apache and tomcat also??

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: => http://serverfault.com (But: A DNS server that required a restart when you edited DNS information would not be fit for purpose. :) )

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated which DNS server you're using. If it's BIND then just do `rndc reload`. That causes named to reload the config and zone files without doing a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question might be malformed, but you can do this right now by just sending `named` a `SIGHUP` which will make it reload the name database.